# angularjs conditional directive only on desktop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to put a directive on an element only if it's not viewed from mobile. As it's an externally maintained plugin I don't want to modify the directive itself. What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Is the device detection a part of the question or do you have that already?

Comment: @tasseKATT I have that already but now that you mentioned it I would appreciate it if you include that too as mine is hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directive that performs the detection (or receives it), adds the directive if not viewed from mobile, removes itself from the element and then compiles the element.

HTML:

```
<div not-on-mobile="external-directive">Hello.</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('notOnMobile', function($compile) {

  // Perform detection.
  // This code will only run once for the entire application (if directive is present at least once).
  // Can be moved into the compile function if detection result needs to be passed as attribute.
  var onMobile = false;

  return {
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      if (!onMobile) tElement.attr(tAttrs.notOnMobile, '');

      tElement.removeAttr('not-on-mobile');

      return function postLink(scope, element) {

        $compile(element)(scope);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/nJntmfiLZ20JCdSWiRDQ?p=preview