# ng-keydown event double fire with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've used the code found in the link below, because I want a directive to be added to a certain textarea only if the user is using a desktop. This same textarea also has a ng-keydown directive that's strangely being double fired at each new key pressed when this code is added.

Any idea why it's happening or how can I solve it?

[angularjs-conditional-directive-only-on-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679153/)

---

Update:

Also a strange behavior is that when you delete the last character of a word, it automatically deletes a previous space (if there is some).

To test it, open the console and check that at any key press, you will get the message "teste1" twice

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vye7k6d/)

relevant part of this code:

```
myApp.directive('notOnMobile', function($compile) {
    // Perform detection.
    // This code will only run once for the entire application (if directive is present at least once).
    // Can be moved into the compile function if detection result needs to be passed as attribute.
    var onMobile = false;

    return {
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            if (!onMobile) tElement.attr(tAttrs.notOnMobile, '');
            tElement.removeAttr('not-on-mobile');

            return function postLink(scope, element) {
                $compile(element)(scope);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and

```
<textarea ng-model="main.queryString"
          rows="1"
          ng-keydown="main.textareaAction($event)"
          not-on-mobile="auto-focus"></textarea>
```

Comment: please create a jsFiddle, or jsbin, with your code.

Comment: there it is, @JoaozitoPolo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the terminal and priority for the directive. So it won't compile the element twice:

```
myApp.directive('notOnMobile', function($compile) {
// Perform detection.
// This code will only run once for the entire application (if directive is present at least once).
// Can be moved into the compile function if detection result needs to be passed as attribute.
var onMobile = false;

return {
    terminal:true,
    priority:1001,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
        if (!onMobile) tElement.attr(tAttrs.notOnMobile, '');
        tElement.removeAttr('not-on-mobile');

        return function postLink(scope, element) {
            $compile(element)(scope);
        };
    }
};
});
```

Find the working code sample here https://jsfiddle.net/h1gr0dwp/

**EDIT:**

You can find a explanation for terminal and priority here [Add directives from directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224028/add-directives-from-directive-in-angularjs/19228302#19228302)